Low new battery performance on Ubuntu 20.04 + slow to detect charger
I bought a new original battery for Lenovo X1 3rd Gen but the battery life did not get better, it might even have worsened. Just runs 3 hours max on full battery and much less when I make videocalls.
Also Ubuntu detects charging of the battery very slowly. The 'battery-charging' symbol only switches on a couple of minutes after plugging in. Same goes for unplugging.
I have tried the top three suggestions from this thread: Battery not charging but detected, which include going into boot menu (BIOS) and disabling battery as well as pressing 10 seconds power button before booting up. Nothing worked so far.
Any help very welcome!
I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Install tlp. sudo apt install tlp && sudo tlp start. Also, try Ubuntu 24.04 instead.

Isn't TLP just an option to save some battery life? I am trying to fix something else which is the right detection of the charger by Ubuntu as well as the correct battery performance.
Maybe I didn't explain right. It's a NEW battery so it's not possible that it just runs for three hours max. It seems that the old battery setup or drivers or something like that are still in the 'old' configuration (i.e. Ubuntu seems to think that it's still the old battery with low performance). Does that make any sense?

Yes, TLP will increase battery life. I don't know the calibration you are referring to exists, but let's wait for other people's answers

I replaced the ten year old battery in my Toshiba with a new one, and everything was great for about three months.
Then today, it was stuck at 20% charge. Attaching the charger would prevent the 20% decreasing but it would not increase the percentage charge either. I tried everything in the big thread, holding down the power button for 10 seconds from switched off. Actually also tried disconnecting both the battery and the cmos battery physically after removing the back panel. That did not work either. I did boot up once just with the main battery disconnected to prove the health of the power supply, but it seemed to be fine.
So what brought it back to life was this - I let it run on battery only so that the capacity dropped from 20% to about 18%. Then when I reconnected the power cord, the orange charging light went on and the percentage started increasing!
I put it down to something in the battery pack - not in the PC circuitry, not in the power supply either. Those batteries have their lithium cells but I think they also have a microprocessor which makes various decisions and among other things makes sure nothing catches fire. So for some reason that microprocessor had decided against charging until that discharging a little was allowed, not sure why, what it was thinking.
